# phpMyAdmin not showing icons

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just reinstalled phpMyAdmin due to a problem I had, that's besides the point. All the icons, such as the ones on the left side of the page, do not show. This is on every page I go to that no icons are visible. However, when I right click the empty box where the icon is supposed to be, then click open image in new tab, the correct image shows.

Would someone explain how to get the icons showing?

[image]

Comment: How did you install phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I downloaded through their site, if that's what you mean?

Comment: Are you on Safari 5? This could be the problem. https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/3940/

Answer (score 6):

I had some problem using nginx&apache, it was solved by adding in nginx configuration file this lines:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
        root /usr/share/;
    }
}
```

Where /usr/share is the directory contains phpmyadmin folder and 8080 is the port using by apache.

Comment: This did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: Clearing cache which is empty cache in safari does not work please.

Comment: Which Safari version?

Comment: Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.4)